# Oauth2 github connection with feathersjs hosted on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I have created an Oauth flow on github with a FeathersJS backend. When running this on localhost it is all working fine. Currently, I am testing the deployment to AWS on EC2 and on the EC2 instance, I can't get the flow to work. I get the redirect_uri_error.

```
{
"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
"error_description": "The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.",
"error_uri": "https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors/#redirect-uri-mismatch(2)"
}
```

I think feathers automatically creates the redirect uri from the parameters in the config files. According to the docs that uri looks like this: `http(s)://hostname[:port]/auth/<provider>/callback`.  I am running the app in production mode with the settings below. What am I doing wrong?

default.json:

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3030,
  "public": "../public/",
  "paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 50
  },
  "mongodb": "my_mongo_connection_string",
  "authentication": {
    "secret": "my_auth_secret",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "service": "users",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "type": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://example.com",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "entity": "user",
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
    "github": {
      "clientID": "my_client_id",
      "clientSecret": "my_client_secret",
      "successRedirect": "/"
    },
    "cookie": {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "feathers-jwt",
      "httpOnly": false,
      "secure": false
    }
  }
}
```

production.json

```
{
  "host": "my-ec2-instance.compute.amazonaws.com",
  "port": "3030"
}
```

Github config 
[image: github config]

EDIT: Changed succesRedirect to "/"

Comment: Admittedly I've never used feathersjs before, but just looking at that configuration file the github property `successRedirect` pops out at me. Is that perhaps what it is using for the `redirect_uri`? In which case you need to update it to something other than `localhost`. I'm also puzzled by how you arrived at the `/auth/github/callback` path you have configured for the callback in GitHub. Shouldn't that path match the path you have configured in `successRedirect`?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for answering. The successRedirect is a link that the feathers backend redirects you to when all has gone well. I think that what happens is: you visit http://backend/auth/github. Feathers redirects you to Github. You approve the access. Github redirects you to feathers backend (http://backend/auth/github/callback). If all is successful, feathers redirects you to the successRedirect URI. So I don't think that should matter. But maybe someone can correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you do what the error message set and set the same URL in your application configuration on GitHub? Also, production applications are expected to run on port 80.

Comment: Hi Daff, thanks for answering. It is the same URL. I tried running the app with sudo on port 80 (nothing like nginx in between). I tried it with specifying the callbackURL and without specifying the callbackURL in default.json. It still doesn't work. The URL on github is the same. Like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution to this problem. In production mode, the feathers application still takes the URL from default.json to build the callback URL. Therefore, the production URL should not only be filled in in production.json, but the same URL should be entered in default.json as well.

Comment: the configuration to use is determined by the NODE_ENV var.  So on your production server, set NODE_ENV=production and then it will override what's in default.json with what's in production.json

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example code in [this feathersjs blog post](https://blog.feathersjs.com/how-to-setup-oauth-flow-with-featherjs-522bdecb10a8), it appears you need to add a `callbackURL` parameter in your `github` configuration section, with the same value that you configured in the GitHub **Authorization callback URL** setting.

Also, I think you will need to modify the `github.successRedirect` setting to be `http://my-ec2-instance.compute.amazonaws.com:3030/redirect` when running on the EC2 server, because the default value you have configured of `localhost` will definitely not work when it is running on EC2.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried adding the callbackURL (my-ec2-instance.compute.amazonaws.com:3030/auth/github/callback) as well. That didn't work. Also, I am currently redirecting to "/", which should not be a problem. Thanks for answering.